# Django: list index out of range

Tags: python, django

I have the following `MultilingualQuerySet`: `super_guest = self.request.event.surveys.get_super_guests()`

Out of this, I filter a variable that I return as a context variable. (There are several different context variables.)

```
context["reason_for_attending"] = list(filter(
    lambda question: question.focus == QuestionFocus.REASON_FOR_ATTENDING,
    super_guest
))[0]
```

Now it all works great as long there is an entry in the database. However, it can happen, that there are no "responses" yet. Then I get a `list index out of range` error. The reason is the `[0]`. Do you have a solution in mind?

Comment: It is possible that there is no item in `super_guest` for which the condition holds, or `super_guest` is simply empty.

Comment: Yes, exactly that can be the case.

Comment: Technically @WillemVanOnsem has the _perfect_ answer. OTOH I would recommend to cram less code into one statement and make the code more readable. Then avoiding this kind of error would be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because no item in `super_guest` matches the given condition (and `super_guest` might simply be empty as well).

You can use [**`next(..)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#next) here, and pass a default value, for example:

```
context['reason_for_attending'] = next(filter(
    lambda question: question.focus == QuestionFocus.REASON_FOR_ATTENDING,
    super_guest
), None)
```

If there are no elements, then `context['reason_for_attending']` will be `None`. You can then do some proper rendering in the template.